# ifstream is duplicating data in a file

Tags: duplicates, ifstream

So I'm a bit puzzled by this, I can't work out exactly what is happening with my file input here. I should point out that I just ported this to Windows, and this does run correctly and as expected on Mac OS X.

Basically, my issue is that my ifstream appears to be copying the tail portion of an input file twice when reading it in. For example, if my input was:

```
Daisy, Daisy, give me your answer, do,
I'm half crazy all for the love of you.
It won't be a stylish marriage,
I can't afford a carriage,
But you'd look sweet upon the seat
Of a bicycle built for two.
```

The ifstream will read in as follows:

```
Daisy, Daisy, give me your answer, do,
I'm half crazy all for the love of you.
It won't be a stylish marriage,
I can't afford a carriage,
But you'd look sweet upon the seat
Of a bicycle built for two. 
I can't afford a carriage,
But you'd look sweet upon the seat
Of a bicycle built for two.
```

This is the code in question:

```
std::ifstream initialResults(inputFileLocation.toStdString().c_str());
std::string fileInMemory;
initialResults.seekg(0,initialResults.end);
fileInMemory.resize(initialResults.tellg());
initialResults.seekg(0,initialResults.beg);
initialResults.read(&fileInMemory[0],fileInMemory.size());
initialResults.close
//Printing here, the file in memory already contains the duplicate entries
std::cout << fileInMemory << "\n";
```

I am not sure at all what is causing this behavior. I am not very familiar with developing on Windows opposed to Mac, and considering the program is identical, yet produces these differing results I am going to go out on a limb and say it's something Window's specific. Perhaps a difference in the function calls to end and beg? But I can't imagine why it would recopy the tail portion of the file. Yes, I have checked the file, and it does not have the duplicate entry within it.

Comment: I've duplicated your code here using a stringstream but I can't find anything you did wrong. (Except that you're missing the parenthesis to `initialResults.close`. -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ceb16d94b83b843bd3796ffb9d2a10d-b54d854fe598111a256b22e5ef8b561f

Answer (score 0):

After further research I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the carriage-return/line-feed issue in Windows. You need to open your file in binary mode `ios_base::binary` to suppress the conversion.